# Sending mail to 100 users using SSIS mail task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have to send mails to 100 people by using SSIS send mail task. but in SSIS mail box To address text box is having  255 characters limit where it's not allowing me to do. So could you please suggest the best way to achieve this..?

Comment: `Loop Container`...get the emails from a txt file and send it one by one in the loop ;)

Comment: I'm newbie to SSIS. could you please share some links so that i can try.

Comment: You can check this one*you can replace the script task with your mail task, but the logic should be the same: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/71485/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

[image]

First task (GetUnsentEmail(s)) to select Email address (stored in a table) where 'flag' = 0 and puts those records into an object variable.
The Foreach Loop Container loops through each record in that object variable and:

- puts values into variables
- executes the task "Send Mail Task"  which uses those variables to
  send the email
- executes the sql task "Update send email table" which sets 'flag' to 1

I hope this help.